# VB.NET StreamWriter Expression expected

Tags: .net, vb.net, streamwriter

I've been look at this for the last hour or so. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

```
ManagerHtml = ManagerHtml.Replace("##Alerts_Popup##",AlertsPopup)

Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(SitePath & "slaOverViewPages\" & Manager("UserID") & "_" & Manager("Adjuster") & "_" & Module(1) & ".html")
sw.Write(ManagerHtml)
sw.Close()
```

This is the compiler error `BC30201: Expression expected.` The line that caused it is the `Dim sw` line.

Thanks for you help.

Nalum

Comment: If that were the case would it not show a line where there was SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide more information on what does the Module(1) returns? or can you try to move code into a separate lines like

```
Dim moduleName as String = Module(1)
```

and then using the variable moduleName in your code statement statement.

Comment: `Module()` is an array of string values. `Module(1)` returns `Recovery`. Will try what you have suggested.

Comment: That wasn't the problem but what you said gave me the answer. The variable was `Modules()` not `Module()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing those double quotes in Manager("xx") are confusing things. What happens if you use single quotes?

Comment: Can't use single quotes as they are comments in vb.net